# How to simulate video playing in Netflix without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, netflix

I'm trying to write a chrome extension where I want to be able to start playing a Netflix video from the main page without having to navigate to the video URL using something like `window.location.href = '...'`, which would cause the page to reload. I want to do this without reloading the page because the content script of a chrome extension is re-injected every time a page reload happens, which I don't want to happen every time.

For example, if you go to the netflix website and click on a movie, the video will start playing without actually doing a full page reload. This suggests that changes to the DOM are triggered via JavaScript? Does anyone know how this is done?

I tried looking at some of the Javascript code to see if there was a function I could call to trigger some sort of event, but the code was too complicated to understand. So another approach I thought of was to do a `fetch` with the url of the video that I want to play, and then simply replace the contents of the `body` element with that of the fetched html. For example:

```
fetch("https://www.netflix.com/watch/70174779")
  .then(function(response) {
    response.text().then(function(html) {
      var parser = new DOMParser();
      var doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
      document.getElementsByTagName(
        "body"
      )[0].innerHTML = doc.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML;
    });
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log("Fetch Error :-S", err);
  });
```

However, when I run this in the Chrome DevTools console, it just results in an empty page. I don't get any helpful errors either. I also tried replacing the entire html contents:

```
fetch("https://www.netflix.com/watch/70174779")
  .then(function(response) {
    response.text().then(function(html) {
      document.open();
      document.write(html);
      document.close();
    });
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log("Fetch Error :-S", err);
  });
```

But this also didn't work, and I get a bunch of errors in the console.

Comment: I don't believe Netflix would allow to read their resources from untrusted sources. Didn't you read about CORS?

Comment: A video player in modern web sites is usually based on complex DASH code that should be loaded dynamically by the site. The only universal approach is to reverse-engineer the page code and trigger the correct routine artificially.

Comment: @wOxxOm what is DASH?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Adaptive_Streaming_over_HTTP

Comment: @wOxxOm Also, I don't really understand why the second approach wouldn't work? I'm basically replacing the entire contents of the page, so why is the result not the same as if I had actually navigated to that url in the browser?

Comment: Because browsers have security restrictions on document.write regarding scripts.